# Java run wont work in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Hello i have a simple program in java using `vscode` editor and i am working in `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I am using this [java-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSnake.java-debug) extension with command `alt + c` to compile and `alt + r` to run the compiled program of the selected files.

**Compile OK**

[image: compile ok]

**No output on RUN**

[image: run not ok]

#### But the run process wont work while the command compile works perfectly. Did i missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have added custom task for Java. 
`Tasks.json` need to be updated.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "javac",
    "showOutput": "always",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-d","${workspaceRoot}\\build\\classes","${workspaceRoot}\\src\\main\\java\\*.java"]
}
```

Comment: but can you explain where is the `Tasks.json` file is? because there is no java found in debug configuration.

Comment: To start you need a task runner for your project, which is where you will...you guessed it...configure tasks. Hit Ctrl + Shift + P to bring up the command palette. Search for "task" and you'll get the Configure Task Runner command. Select it and press Enter to generate a tasks.json file.
Below link should help you. 
http://www.westerndevs.com/custom-tasks-for-java-in-visual-studio-code/

Comment: sure2 please wait as i try